# Power BI report integration from local server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2012

how to integrate PowerBI reports from local system and use them in the asp.net MVC? i'm trying to integrate powerBI report in my project which is published on powerBI report server in my system (not online powerBI). while googling i'm not able to find what i needed, most of them recommends to publish the report to cloud and embed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed a report from Power BI Report Server, add an `iframe` in your app, with source the URL of the report, and added the following query string parameter `?rs:embed=true`. For example:

```
https://myserver/reports/powerbi/Sales?rs:embed=true
```

If your app will be used inside your network, this is enough. But if you want to use it by users over internet (users, which are not in your network), then you will need to expose the Power BI Report Server's reports portal to the world too.

For more information see:

- [Embed a Power BI Report Server report using an iFrame in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed)
- [Embedding Power BI Reports with Power BI Report Server](https://www.kasperonbi.com/embedding-power-bi-reports-with-power-bi-report-server/)
- [Planning for Extranet or Internet Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159272(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (PBIRS is in fact SSRS).